# Selecting an element after the currently matched Element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have HTML like this:

```
<div id="Div1">...</div>
<div class="someClass">...</div>
<div id="Div2">...</div>
<div class="someClass">...</div>
<div id="Div3">...</div>
<div class="someClass">...</div>
```

So I have unique DIVs but also some that are indistinguishable from each other.
I want to remove a div and the one below it, for example I want to remove Div2 and the someClass below it to end up with:

```
<div id="Div1">...</div>
<div class="someClass">...</div> <!-- That is the one after Div1 -->
<div id="Div3">...</div>
<div class="someClass">...</div>
```

I'm assuming the [Next Siblings selector ~](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) would help, but that removes all. Trying to use :first did not do anything.

```
$("#Div2 ~ .someClass:first").remove();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$("#Div2 ~ .someClass").first().remove();
```

You can also use the [next adjacent selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/):

```
$("#Div2 + .someClass").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Another fun way to do the same thing](http://jsfiddle.net/8PHZB/)

```
$("#Div2").next().remove().end().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

To be more innovative:

```
$("#Div2").next().andSelf().remove()
```